# Subgroup generated by $G-H$ , $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that group generated by $G - H$ equals $G$, where $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the fact that a group cannot be written as the union of two proper subgroups: obviously $G=H \cup \langle G-H\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $G-H\subseteq \langle G-H\rangle$. To see that also $H\subseteq\langle G-H\rangle$, for given $h\in H$ pick $g\in G-H$ (which is possible because $H$ is a proper subgroup). Then also $hg^{-1}\notin H$, hence $h = hg^{-1}\cdot g\in\langle G-H\rangle$.